# Incrementar una variable de tipo data Microprocesador

Tags: haskell

Me piden no repetir esta logica `pC microprocesador + 1` ya no se me ocurre una idea de como hacerlo, creo que me piden que de alguna forma se autoincremente.

```
data Microprocesador = Microprocesador {
  nombre :: String,
  memory :: [Int],
  a :: Int,
  b :: Int,
  pC :: Int,
  mensajeDeError :: String
} deriving(Show)

type Intruccion = Microprocesador -> Microprocesador

nop :: Instruccion
nop microprocesador = microprocesador { pC = pC microprocesador + 1 }

lodv :: Int -> Instruccion
lodv valor microprocesador = microprocesador {
  a = a microprocesador + valor,
  pC = pC microprocesador + 1
}

swap :: Instruccion
swap microprocesador = microprocesador {
  b = a microprocesador,
  a = b microprocesador,
  pC = pC microprocesador + 1
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta por la comunidad te invito a leer **[ask]**

Comment: ¿De qué supuesto partes?¿qué es lo que tienes que hacer? ¿qué conoces de haskell? Así por encima, tendrías que tener una función *evaluadora* a la que le pasas *operaciones*.  Al evaluar es donde se incrementa el *PC* (o se salta a otra dirección). Pero sin saber más del ejercicio poco más se puede decir.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función que se encargue de incrementar el contador de programa, y otra función que se encargue de ejecutar las instrucciones.

## Incrementar contador de programa

```
nextPC :: Instruccion
nextPC microprocesador = microprocesador { pC = pC microprocesador + 1 }
```

La función `nextPC` toma un microprocesador y devuelve el mismo microprocesador, pero con el contador incrementado.

## Ejecutar instrucción

```
run :: Instruccion -> Instruccion
run = (.) nextPC
```

La función `run` toma una instrucción y devuelve otra instrucción. Lo que hace es componer la instrucción que reciba con la función `nextPC`: así primero realizará la lógica de la instrucción que reciba, y luego le incrementará el contador de programa.

Esta función también podría escribirse así, si te resulta más fácil de ver:

```
run :: Instruccion -> Microprocesador -> Microprocesador
run instruccion microprocesador = nextPC (instruccion microprocesador)
```

Así queda explícito que lo que la función recibe es una instrucción y un microprocesador, y que ejecuta la instrucción recibida al microprocesador recibido, y luego le incrementa el contador de programa con `nextPC`.

## Definir instrucciones

Dado que el contador de programa se incrementará mediante la función `run`, debes modificar tus instrucciones. Por ejemplo, la función `nop` no hará nada:

```
nop :: Instruccion
nop microprocesador = microprocesador
```

Devuelve lo que recibe, es decir, actúa como la función identidad `id`, así que puedes escribirla directamente como:

```
nop :: Instruccion
nop = id
```

Y lo mismo con el resto de funciones:

```
lodv :: Int -> Instruccion
lodv valor microprocesador = microprocesador { a = a microprocesador + valor }

swap :: Instruccion
swap microprocesador = microprocesador { b = a microprocesador, a = b microprocesador }
```

## Ejemplo

Ahora puedes ejecutar tus instrucciones como:

```
ghci> let x = Microprocesador "a" [] 0 1 2 ""
ghci> run nop x
Microprocesador {nombre = "a", memory = [], a = 0, b = 1, pC = 3, mensajeDeError = ""}
```